# only the root route works in a fresh Laravel-8 installation, all other give 404

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm running Laravel 8.0.1 on an Apache24 with PHP74

When I create a new project, the welcome pages renders fine. If I add another route, I always get a 404

```
% composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel test123
Installing laravel/laravel (v8.0.1)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v8.0.1): Loading from cache
...
...
Package manifest generated successfully.
69 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> @php artisan key:generate --ansi
Application key set successfully.
%
% cd test123
% chmod a+w storage/logs/ storage/framework/sessions/ storage/framework/views/ bootstrap/cache/
% npm install
% npm run dev
```

The Laravel Page now renders fine. Look good for me :)

BUT if I add a new Route to `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
  return view('welcome');
});
```

And try to access the page at /about I'll get a 404
Unfortunately the `storage/logs/laravel.log` is empty (there is also no entry when I access the / page)

Comment: a Laravel 404 or a webserver 404? if it s the webserver's 404 page that is usually a misconfiguration with "pretty urls"

Comment: it's a 404 from the webserver... I'll check the config.
Laravel provides a .htaccess file, this one is still in place... i'll report back shortly

Comment: you might need to deal with `AllowOverride` in the site configuration to allow the `.htaccess` file to do what it needs ... but I haven't used apache in a very long time

Answer (score 2):

The ApacheConfiguration had `AllowOverride None` on the DocumentRoot and therefore the .htaccess couldn't override things. Setting this option to All (or the Options mentioned in the .htaccess File) did the trick

thx to lagbox for pointing me into the right direction